# What's the formula for number of configurations to five shapes with colors

Tags: combinations, factorial

I have triangle, circle, square, diamond, and trapezoid, each with 36 colors. How do I find the possible number of unique configurations of these colored shapes.

Example: One configuration is red triangle, red circle, red square, blue diamond, blue trapezoid. Another configuration is red triangle, red circle, red square, GREEN diamond, GREEN trapezoid, etc, etc.

Would this formula work? (36!)^4

However, (36!)^4 is over a billion! Can 5 shapes with 36 colors each create over a billion configurations?

Edit: Order of the shape matters and you cannot repeat the shapes, but you can repeat colors. What matters is a combination does not appear twice.

Comment: Are you able to repeat shapes?  Are you able to repeat colors?  Are you able to repeat the same shape-color combination?  Does order matter?  Assuming you are able to repeat shape-color combinations and order matters, you will in fact have $(5\cdot 36)^5\approx 19.9\cdot 10^{11}$ different combinations.  If you can't repeat shapes but can repeat colors and order doesn't matter (i.e. always in order of triangle, circle, square,...) then you have $36^5\approx 6\cdot 10^7$ possible outcomes.  For some other interpretation the number of outcomes can change further.

Comment: Also, for the record "$(36!)^4$ *is over a billion!*" is such a gross understatement.  $36!\approx 3.7\cdot 10^{41}$ is already much greater than a billion.  Raising that to a power makes it absurdly large compared to a number as *small* as a billion.  $(36!)^4\approx 1.9\cdot 10^{166}\gg 10^9$

Comment: Can't repeat shapes, but you can repeat colors. However, the same combination of colored shapes cannot be repeated. You cannot have red triangle, red circle, red square, blue diamond, blue trapezoid appear twice.

Comment: Yes order matters

Comment: (*using clubsuit instead of trapezoid*) So you consider $\color{red}{\triangle\circ}\color{green}{\square\diamondsuit\clubsuit}$ to be the same or a different outcome than $\color{green}{\square\clubsuit}\color{red}{\triangle}\color{green}{\diamondsuit}\color{red}{\circ}$?  If you consider those to be the same, then my answer of $36^5$ still stands.  (*or alternatively if you don't allow the second one since not in the order $\triangle\circ\square\diamondsuit\clubsuit$*)  If you consider them different, then the answer increases by a factor of $5!$ to a new total of $5!\cdot 36^5$

Comment: Those two combinations would be the same and must be counted as one appearance. If 36^5 is the correct answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Wow, so 5 shapes of 36 colors can generate of 60,000,000 unique combinations? That's amazing

Comment: Wait, isn't not allowing a different shape order the same thing as counting a different order of same colored shapes with the original as one appearance?

Comment: Yes.  The question was whether you "counted them as one" or not.  As an aside, an answer of $(36!)^4$ would be the number of ways you could shuffle four decks of cards where each deck has only the cards with numbers $(2,3,4,\dots,10)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result, whatever the interpretation of the problem is, the solution relies on the [Rule of Product(Multiplication Principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

In set theory it is written as $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$

(*the $\times$ on the left hand of the equation is the cartesian product of sets, whereas on the right it is the usual multiplication of real numbers*)

For enumerative combinatorics (*e.g. counting how many possibilities there are for something*) it can be paraphrased in the following way:

> When attempting to count how many outcomes there are for a given scenario, if you can **uniquely** describe **each** possible outcome via a sequence of steps such that
>
> - Every outcome is described by exactly one sequence of choices
> - The number of options for each step in the process is independent of the specific choices picked in earlier steps
>
> the total number of outcomes is then the *product* of the number of options available in each step.

In your specific example, we break it down via multiplication principle using the steps:

- Pick the color of the triangle (36 choices)
- Pick the color of the circle (36 choices)
- Pick the color of the square (36 choices)
- Pick the color of the diamond (36 choices)
- Pick the color of the trapezoid (36 choices)

The total is then the product of the number of choices, $36\cdot 36\cdot 36\cdot 36\cdot 36=36^5$

*NOTE*: The phrasing I used only says that the **number** of choices at each step isn't allowed to change based on earlier selections, however the specific choices available themselves are able to change.

For example, trying to arrange the five shapes in a line (no color for this example)

- Pick the location of the triangle (5 choices)  (*specifically the first spot, second spot, third spot,...*)
- Pick the location of the circle (4 choices)  (*specifically if the triangle was in the first spot the circle could go in positions 2,3,4,5.  If the triangle was in the second spot the circle could go in positions 1,3,4,5.  If the triangle was in the third spot the circle could go in positions 1,2,4,5.  If the triangle was......*)
- Pick the location of the square (3 choices) (*if the triangle and circle were in the first spot and second spot respectively the square could go in positions 3,4,5.  if the triangle and circle were......*)
- $\vdots$

Multiplying we get $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=5!=120$ ways we can arrange the five shapes.  Note here in this example, at each step, the *number* of options was always the same regardless which specific choices were made in previous steps.  Regardless which two spaces the triangle and circle occupied there were always three options available for where the square could be placed.

---

For a final example, we ask the question for how many arrangements of the five shapes with 36 available colors for each shape where colors can be repeated but shapes could not where shapes could appear in any order and order matters there are.

Breaking apart via multiplication principle yet again, we get the sequence of steps:

- Pick how the shapes are each colored ($36^5$ options.  See first example)
- Pick how the shapes are arranged in the line ($5!$ options.  See second example)

We get here $5!\cdot 36^5$ possible outcomes.